# Why is the notation $\text{Hom}_C(A,B)$ used to denote morphisms?

Tags: category-theory, soft-question, math-history

In category theory, the set of morphisms between two objects A and B of a category C is denoted $\text{Hom}_C(A,B)$. Historically or practically, why is this notation used? Of course, Hom likely refers to the concept of a homomorphism, but since category theory is more general, and morphisms need not be homomorphisms, why do we still use the notation "Hom"?

> Is there a historical reason we use "Hom" to denote morphisms based on the development of category theory and if so, what is it? Alternatively, is there an express purpose to the notation?

Comment: Without knowing any of the history here, my guess is the notation first appeared in algebra, then was appropriated by category theory.